# APN Requires mcc and mnc but my carrier requires none

Tags: cyanogenmod, 3g, apn

I used to specify only the Name and APN fields whenever I needed to configure my carrier's APN. I've just rooted my Galaxy Nexus with Cyanogemod and whenever I try to set the APN it prompts me to enter the mcc and mnc number's which my carrier doesn't specify.

How can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! Ok I'm no where near a cellular expert but based on a wild guess I searched for carrier APNs and found [here](http://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/f299/mcc-mnc-code-here-all-country-768614/) a list of APNs per carrier per country. I guess these are always required but somehow cyanogenmod is not configured to determine these codes automatically.

While this may help others facing the same problem, I hope someone with real insight shares the knowledge